# How to use JSONP with Object Oriented Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I am new to JSONP and had implemented cross domain functionality for my application and everything is working fine. Now i want to change my javascript code to apply object orientation.

My api is

```
http://localhost:8080/myApplication/getComments?callback=displayComments

CrossDomain.prototype.displayComments = function(data) {
    // code to display the comments
}
```

Now I am getting an error in firebug given below

```
ReferenceError: displayComments is not defined
```

I changed the api to

```
http://localhost:8080/myApplication/getComments?callback=this.displayComments
```

and found that the function is appended inline to the callback like this

```
http://localhost:8080/myApplication/getComments?callback=callback=function (jsonData)
{ 
    //code to display the comments
}
```

this time another error in firebug

```
SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
```

I have a doubt whether to use JSONP in object oriented javascript or not.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `displayComments` has to be a global function otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point in defining the function on the prototype of a function unless you are going to create instances of that function, so start by doing that.

```
var myCrossDomain = new CrossDomain();
```

Then you have to call the method on the object, not as a global (it isn't a global, so you can't do that anyway)

```
var uri = "http://localhost:8080/myApplication/getComments?callback=" + 
    encodeURIComponent("myCrossDomain.displayComments");
```

---

In response to edits and comments:

> Yes i am creating an instance of this in another js file

Then reference it as shown above.

> I changed the api to
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/myApplication/getComments?callback=this.displayComments
> ```

It's JSON-P. It runs by adding a new script element. Everything gets called in the global context. That is going to call `this.displayComments` which will be the same as `window.displayComments`.

If you want to call your method directly, then you need to specify the global variable holding the instance explicitly.

If you don't want to call it directly then you can use the more traditional approach of generating a new, anonymous function which has access to said object through a closure, assigning that function to a global variable (with a unique name) and using that name as your callback argument.

> and found that the function is appended inline to the callback like this
>
> ```
> http://localhost:8080/myApplication/getComments?callback=callback=function (jsonData)
> ```

You haven't shown us the code that creates the URI so we can't tell why that might be the case.

Comment: Yes i am creating an instance of this in another js file

Comment: Thanks Quentin! Problem solved. I have added the following line in the constructor

`window["cds"] = this;`

and called the api as follows

`"http://localhost:8080/myApplication/getComments?callback=" + 
    encodeURIComponent("cds['displayComments']");`